# Download all content of remote ftp directory and subdirectories

Tags: bash, ftp, wget

Lets assume that I have some directory on remote ftp - ftp.test.com/pub/dir1/remotedirectory/ with some files and directories inside.

Is there any way, using bash script, download all content from ftp.test.com/pub/dir1/remotedirectory/ and put it in order, as it was on remote FTP?

Example:

```
ftp.test.com/pub/dir1/remotedirectory/testfile.doc   ==> /tmp/testfile.doc
ftp.test.com/pub/dir1/remotedirectory/somedir/file.txt   ==> /tmp/somedir/file.txt
```

I know that I can use wget to download single file, but how to download all files and subdirectories?

Comment: You can use wget with -r

Comment: Thanks Roman! It helped me a lot!

Spasibo  :)